# How to use lifecycle method getDerivedStateFromProps as opposed to componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

It looks like `componentWillReceiveProps` is going to be completely phased out in coming releases, in favor of a new lifecycle method `getDerivedStateFromProps`:[static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Upon inspection, it looks like you are now unable to make a direct comparison between `this.props` and `nextProps`, like you can in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Is there any way around this?

Also, it now returns an object. Am I correct to assume that the return value is essentially `this.setState`?

Below is an example I found online: [State derived from props/state](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0006-static-lifecycle-methods.md#state-derived-from-propsstate).

**Before**

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    derivedData: computeDerivedState(this.props)
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.someValue !== nextProps.someValue) {
      this.setState({
        derivedData: computeDerivedState(nextProps)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**After**

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  // Initialize state in constructor,
  // Or with a property initializer.
  state = {};

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.someMirroredValue !== nextProps.someValue) {
      return {
        derivedData: computeDerivedState(nextProps),
        someMirroredValue: nextProps.someValue
      };
    }

    // Return null to indicate no change to state.
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Title should be "how to make things work despite React team doing everything to oppose it"

Answer (score 119, accepted):

About the removal of `componentWillReceiveProps`: you should be able to handle its uses with a combination of `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`, see [the React blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#examples) for example migrations. And yes, the object returned by `getDerivedStateFromProps` updates the state similarly to an object passed to `setState`.

In case you really need the old value of a prop, you can always cache it in your state with something like this:

```
state = {
  cachedSomeProp: null
  // ... rest of initial state
};

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  // do things with nextProps.someProp and prevState.cachedSomeProp
  return {
    cachedSomeProp: nextProps.someProp,
    // ... other derived state properties
  };
}
```

Anything that doesn't affect the state can be put in `componentDidUpdate`, and there's even a `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` for very low-level stuff.

UPDATE: To get a feel for the new (and old) lifecycle methods, the [react-lifecycle-visualizer](https://github.com/Oblosys/react-lifecycle-visualizer#readme) package may be helpful.

Comment: Ugh, I messed up the question. I actually meant `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I had thought of using my state to hold previous props, but I really wanted to avoid the extra code and logic it takes to implement it. I'll looking into some of the other things you bring up. Much thanks!

Comment: Having to store a previous prop in a state is just a boilerplate workaround for this hard-to-understand React API change. For the eyes of many developers this looks like an antipattern and a regression change. Not criticising you Oblosys, but the React team.

Comment: @AxeEffect This is because **`getDerivedStateFromProps` was never really intended for memoization**. Please see my answer below where I described **the recommended approach** instead.

Comment: is that a typo? Did you miss `...`? That is should we return the entire state object or only the part that we care about.

Comment: You should just return the derived state properties. I denoted possible other derived properties with `..` to avoid  confusion with `...`, but `// ...` is better.

Answer (score 63):

As we **[recently posted on the React blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html),** in the vast majority of cases **you don't need `getDerivedStateFromProps` at all**.

If you just want to compute some derived data, either:

1. Do it right inside `render`
2. Or, if re-calculating it is expensive, use a memoization helper like `memoize-one`.

Here's the simplest "after" example:

```
import memoize from "memoize-one";

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  getDerivedData = memoize(computeDerivedState);

  render() {
    const derivedData = this.getDerivedData(this.props.someValue);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Check out **[this section of the blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization)** to learn more.

Comment: If it's not needed in _vast_ majority of cases, then I'm surprised this was such a badly needed change, the one that will break thousands of working projects. Looks like React team started over engineering.

Comment: What change are you referring to? What will break working projects? There was no breaking change.

Comment: Change from componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps. It's not breaking but forcing to refactor all existing code, which is very time consuming. And seems to very little benefit since you say you shouldn't be using it at all in vast majority of cases. Why go through the hassle of changing API for something that shouldn't even be used in the first place.

Comment: I would love a response to this comment from Dan Abramov.

Comment: @DanAbramov any answer on why this change came to be?

Comment: Actually in our projects this is used a lot. For showing things like Snackbars on screens for when new data comes down, 1 example. ```componentWillReceiveProps``` was simple and it worked. Why remove it for this static garbage...

Comment: @DanAbramov I'm curious too about an answer, just why?

Comment: @DanAbramov I had use case where I directly (without any conditions) fetch data in componentwillReceive Props, and store result in state. what is best way to transition this to new react lifecycle methods? (don't easily see one)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Dan Abramov

> Do it right inside render

We actually use that approach with memoise one for any kind of proxying props to state calculations.

Our code looks this way

```
// ./decorators/memoized.js  
import memoizeOne from 'memoize-one';

export function memoized(target, key, descriptor) {
  descriptor.value = memoizeOne(descriptor.value);
  return descriptor;
}

// ./components/exampleComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import { memoized } from 'src/decorators';

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  buildValuesFromProps() {
    const {
      watchedProp1,
      watchedProp2,
      watchedProp3,
      watchedProp4,
      watchedProp5,
    } = this.props
    return {
      value1: buildValue1(watchedProp1, watchedProp2),
      value2: buildValue2(watchedProp1, watchedProp3, watchedProp5),
      value3: buildValue3(watchedProp3, watchedProp4, watchedProp5),
    }
  }

  @memoized
  buildValue1(watchedProp1, watchedProp2) {
    return ...;
  }

  @memoized
  buildValue2(watchedProp1, watchedProp3, watchedProp5) {
    return ...;
  }

  @memoized
  buildValue3(watchedProp3, watchedProp4, watchedProp5) {
    return ...;
  }

  render() {
    const {
      value1,
      value2,
      value3
    } = this.buildValuesFromProps();

    return (
      <div>
        <Component1 value={value1}>
        <Component2 value={value2}>
        <Component3 value={value3}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The benefits of it are that you don't need to code tons of comparison boilerplate inside `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentWillReceiveProps` and you can skip copy-paste initialization inside a constructor.

**NOTE:**

This approach is used only for proxying the props to state, in case you have some inner state logic it still needs to be handled in component lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

**getDerivedStateFromProps** is used whenever you want to update state before render and update with the condition of props

GetDerivedStateFromPropd  updating the stats value  with the help of props value

read [https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_lifecycle.asp#:~:text=Lifecycle%20of%20Components,Mounting%2C%20Updating%2C%20and%20Unmounting](https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_lifecycle.asp#:%7E:text=Lifecycle%20of%20Components,Mounting%2C%20Updating%2C%20and%20Unmounting).