# React state update from Redux causing Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm rather new to React and Redux, and I have gotten a bit stuck when displaying the error state based on an error response from the server (using express).

Most of the other similar issues I've researched are related to onClick, onSubmit, or onChange, but I have not seen one like mine.

Expected result: The error state is retrieved from the store and displayed within the component

The issue stems from this segment:

```
if (nextProps.errors){
  this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });    
}
```

The full Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../css/login.css";
import { loginUser } from "../../redux/actions/authActions";
import TextFieldGroup from "../common/textFieldGroup";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    };
    
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }

    if (nextProps.errors){
        this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });    
    }
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="login">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Log In</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">
                
              </p>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="username"
                  name="username"
                  type="username"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.username}
                  isRequired
                />

                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.password}
                  isRequired
                />
                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

I've tried:

1. Assigning the value to a temp variable, but this is extremely clunky and makes the code confusing in
   my opinion.
2. Validating if it is null/not null, naturally this reinforced the infinite loop or validated
   positively, as it was not null, so the error state never updates on the page.

I am definitely getting the correct error response from the server as I can see it in the Redux dev tools.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use lifecycle method getDerivedStateFromProps as opposed to componentWillReceiveProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617486/how-to-use-lifecycle-method-getderivedstatefromprops-as-opposed-to-componentwill)

Comment: Either use `getDerivedStateFromProps` or adjust the condition in the `componentDidUpdate` method: `if (!this.props.errors && nextProps.errors)` or `this.props.errors !== nextProps.errors`

Comment: Try `if (nextProps.errors !== this.state.errors){` But I don't understand why you need to copy props.errors to state.errors, you can use props.errors directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the condition from:

```
if (nextProps.errors)
```

to:

```
if (this.props.errors !== nextProps.errors)
```

Seems to be working well for now.
Credit to @emile-bergeron for the fix