# How to make use of React setState method using getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my code, I was using `componentWillReceiveProps` which I know has been deprecated, but my code seems to be working fine using that method. This is what I had:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.tableData !== undefined) {
      const data = nextProps.tableData.datapaths.map(item => { return item.row });
      this.setState({ data });
    }
  }
```

Can someone tell me how can I apply the same logic to the method `getDerivedStateFromProps` because it doesn't like and complain when I tried using `setState` method inside this method:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.tableData !== undefined) {
      const data = props.tableData.datapaths.map(item => { return item.row });
      state.data = data;
      this.setState({ data });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use lifecycle method getDerivedStateFromProps as opposed to componentWillReceiveProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617486/how-to-use-lifecycle-method-getderivedstatefromprops-as-opposed-to-componentwill)

Comment: Thanks @Taki for sharing the link. I tried to follow the suggestions provided in that link but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't `setState` inside `getDerivedStateFromProps` , just return the new state :

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (props.tableData !== undefined) {
    const data = props.tableData.datapaths.map(item => { return item.row });

    // this will update the state
    return { data };
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already but I still don't see sorting happening on the table.